# Using Dired's mark containing command (e.g. dired-mark-files-containing-regexp)

Tags: regex, emacs, dired

I'm confused how dired's 'mark containing' (e.g. `dired-mark-files-containing-regexp`)command works.  I have a directory with a bunch of files I accidentally created and want to delete of the form `1-bad-filename.csv-really-bad.csv`.  I want to mark these files and then delete them. Using the regex-tool, I see that `csv-really` should be enough to identify them. But nothing gets marked when I do this:

> 0 matching files marked.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me. It sounds like you are expecting `dired-mark-files-containing-regexp` to match a regexp against a **file name**, instead of against the file **contents**.

If that is what you want, then use command **`dired-mark-files-regexp`** (bound to **`% m`**), not `dired-mark-files-containing-regexp`.